# How to deal with "Starting neo4j failed: Address localhost:7687 is already in use"?

Tags: neo4j

I am using Neo4j Community Edition 3.1.1 on Mac OS X Sierra. Whenever I try to start Neo4j locally via

```
neo4j start
```

I get the following:

```
Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@a8ba98d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. 
Please see attached cause exception.
```

with the following exception at the tail of /usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/3.1.1/libexec/logs/neo4j.log

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.helpers.PortBindException: Address localhost:7687 is already in use, cannot bind to it.
```

I tried running

```
lsof -i -n -P | grep 7687
```

but it came back empty.

Please advise.

Comment: check neo4j.conf and maybe try to change the port

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried that but whatever port I change to, I get the same exception on the new port!!

Comment: You could also try the installer from neo4j.com. You installed with homebrew, right?

Comment: Thanks Martin. I actually tried both.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'd leave this as a comment, but don't have the required rep.

- Are you sure that you have only one version of Neo4j installed?
- Is your installation clean, without any traces of previous installations?
- Is your JDK version >= 8?
- Have you made other changes to your conf file?
- Do you have the desktop app installed? des it work without issues?

Your lsof could be returning an empty value as some pids are only visible to root. Try:

```
sudo netstat -antlp
```

This should return all open ports, check if anything corresponds to 7687.

Also try running neo4j as a service. I believe it's launchctl on Mac (I use systemctl on  Linux) and check if the error persists.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue, notice how neo4js is trying to get to `localhost:7687`?

I checked my /etc/hosts file and sure enough, I had a bogus entry for localhost (from previous testing).

I changed /etc/hosts entry back to
`localhost 127.0.0.1`
Saved, then ran again.
Neo4j started up fine after that.